# Magento Cart Refresh Loop

Tags: magento, cookies

On magento website there is a huge problem with the cart. My store is translated to two languages - latvian and russian and this problem appears in both these languages, but in english everything is just fine. So, the problem is, when I go to my cart after adding products to it, it keeps refreshing constantly in Google Chrome. 
*In Mozilla, Opera* and *IE* everything is good, by the way. I have tried deleting all session files from *var/session* and *var/cache*, cleared cookies, increased cookie lifetime, changed cookie validation options and other but nothing worked. 
Please, help...

Comment: first check your magento logs and as well as browser console

Comment: Thank you. The error is "JQuery not defined". How can I fix that?

Comment: This error is due to jQuery file is not included in your code. Add jQuery file on page to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to jQuery file is not included in your code. Add jQuery file on page to fix that issue.
`app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/page.xml` and then add this :

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.min.js</script></action>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Via Google Chrome developer tools I found out, that one extension causes this problem. But when I delete it, my website breaks. What can I do?

Comment: Can you tell the name of that extension?

Comment: It is ChangePrice by MarKor

Comment: try to remove the jquery file of that extension.